# C#, WCF, When to reuse a client side proxy

Tags: c#, wcf

Im writing an application which transfers files using WCF. The transfers are done in segments so that they can be resumed after any unforeseen interruption.

My question concerns the use of the client side proxy, is it better to keep it open and reuse it to transfer each file segment or should I be reopening it each time I want to send something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reuse your WCF client proxy and that will make your client application faster, as proxy just will initialize once.

Comment: But you need to be careful not to attempt to reuse a proxy that is in the faulted state when employing this strategy.

Comment: MY first thought was to reuse the client proxy but just looking at usage in some of the other applications we have here there seems to be a tendency to use and close them as soon as possible. No one has been able to explain to me why though.

Will do Cocowalla!

Answer (score 11):

The reason to close a proxy as quickly as possible is the fact that you might be having a session in place which ties up system resources (netTcpBinding uses a transport-level session, wsHttpBinding can use security or reliability-based sessions).

But you're right - as long as a client proxy isn't in a faulted state, you can totally reuse it.

If you want to go one step further, and if you can share a common assembly with the service and data contracts between server and client, you could split up the client proxy creation into two steps:

- create a `ChannelFactory<IYourServiceContract>` once and cache that - this is a very expensive and resource-intensive operation; since you need to make this a generic using your service contract (interface), you need to be able to share contracts between server and client
- given that factory, you can create your channels using `factory.CreateChannel()` as needed - this operation is much less "heavy" and can be done quickly and over and over again

This is one possible optimization you could look into - given the scenario that you control both ends of the communication, and you can share the contract assembly between server and client.

Answer (score 1):

Creation of a new proxy takes up about 50-100 ms of time, if your system needs good scaling, it's quite a significant time.

When reusing the proxy, you have to be careful of its state *and* threading issues. Do not try to send data using a proxy that is already busy with sending data. (or receiving) You'll have terrible sleepless nights.

One way of reusing is, having a `[ThreadStatic]` private field for the proxy and testing its state & presence each time you need to send data. If a new thread was created, the thread static field will be null and you'll need to create a proxy. Assuming you have a simple threading model, this will keep the different threads from stepping on each other's toes and you'll have to worry only about the faulted state of the proxy.