# An error in the MSDN walk-through - "How to: Host WCF in a Windows Service Using TCP"

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services, msdn

I've been banging my head against a brick-wall the past 2 days trying to successfully use this example on MSDN:

[How to: Host WCF in a Windows Service Using TCP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649818.aspx)

If you follow the example through and place the Consumer application within the same solution then it runs successfully - even if the service is turned off !

If the service is switched on and the consumer application is published to say a different network drive then it will not run because the WCF is not listening.

The following piece of code in the walk-through is the culprit:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
   if (myServiceHost != null)
   {
       myServiceHost.Close();
   }
   myServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1));
   myServiceHost.Open();
}
```

My friend noticed that if we change `new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1));` to `new ServiceHost(typeof(WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1));` then the WCF will actually start to listen!

Easy to see it's confusion as there is a class called Service1 within the windows service project aswell as the WCF project so the full qualification is required.

Did anyone else encounter this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue (as you know from the [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750413/consuming-a-wcf-service-that-is-hosted-in-a-windows-service-from-outside-solutio/12800645#12800645) in stackoverflow).

Alternatively, you can rename the class Service1 in the namespace WcfServiceLibrary1 to avoid conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

you have to put `using WcfServiceLibrary1;` at the top

Comment: ...have you tried the walkthrough? I put `using WcfServiceLibrary1;` at the top and it runs fine in the virtual environment of VS (the Windows Service does not even need to be switch on within that environment for it to succeed via debugging!) but if you publish the consumer app to a different drive on the network it will fail due to the reasons given.

Answer (score 0):

I also found that the the article references the wrong Service Name. When I tried it I had to use:

```
net.tcp://localhost:8526/Service1/mex
```

in step 8 instead of what was listed.

```
net.tcp://localhost:8526/Service1
```