# Referencing a Wcf Tcp service from within the same solution

Tags: wcf, nettcpbinding, service-reference

I am going through the walkthrough "How to: Use netTcpBinding with Windows Authentication and Transport Security in WCF Calling from Windows Forms"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647180.aspx

When I get to "Step 7: Create a Test Client Application" and substep 5: "5.In the Add Service Reference dialog box, set the Service URI: to net.tcp://localhost:8523/WCFTestService and then click Go"

I get "The URI prefix is not recognized.  Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved".

It's as if the "Add Service Reference" doesn't recognize the "net.tcp" binding.

I'm on Windows 7 x64 using Visual Studio 2012 and my project is targeting x86 and Framework 4.5.

I found this thread

[An error in the MSDN walk-through - "How to: Host WCF in a Windows Service Using TCP"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761107/an-error-in-the-msdn-walk-through-how-to-host-wcf-in-a-windows-service-using)

But they didn't have a problem when the client was in the same solution.  I am.

Service Config:

```
    <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="Publisher.MyServiceBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
        <service name="POC_WcfTcpSubscribePublishService.Publisher">
            <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
                name="NetTcpBindingEndpoint" contract="POC_WcfTcpSubscribePublishService.IPublisher">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
                name="MexTcpBindingEndpoint" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8523/WcfTcpSubscribePublish" />
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

any pointers are welcome.

Comment: Is the service running that you are trying to add a reference to? That's a requirement, I believe - you can run the service project separately from the context menu.

Comment: Sorry for the late response.  This was the problem.  I had thought I was running the service, but when I started it, it was immediately shutting down for a different reason.  Now I can add the service reference to the client project.  Funny, but discovery still doesn't work.

Comment: If you add this response as an answer, I will mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service must be running before you can add a reference to it.

You can run the service project separately from the context menu within Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

You have a service behavior: Publisher.MyServiceBehavior

But you don't apply that service behavior to your service. After service name="..." do this:

behaviorConfiguration="Publisher.MyServiceBehavior"

Comment: Trevor, thanks for the response.  Sorry for the delay, I'm being pulled in many directions.  This was a good catch, but did not solve my problem.  As I replied to "500 - Internal Server Error" above, the problem was that my service would not stay running.  Now that I can run the service, I can reference it in the client.